# Compilation error enum parameter - why?

Tags: c, parameters, enums, typedef

I have the following code blocks

global_definitions.h: (this is included by both header and source file below):

```
typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE = !FALSE } bool;
```

Header-File Log.h:

```
void Log_Leave_Func_Int
(
  Log_Module_ID_t Module_ID,
  const char      *Function_Name,
  const bool      Has_Return_Value,
  const int       Return_Value
);
```

Source-File Log.c:

```
void Log_Leave_Func_Int
(
  Log_Module_ID_t Module_ID,
  const char      *Function_Name,
  const bool      Has_Return_Value,
  const int       Return_Value
)
{
  bool HRetVal = Has_Return_Value;
  /* some code here */
}
```

Now, when compiling my program (using CVI 2012) I receive the error `"Log.h"(366,20)   syntax error; found 'identifier' expecting ')'.` refering to the line in Log.h that reads `const bool      Has_Return_Value,`, which is a complete mystery to me.

I already tried changing the definition of bool to

```
typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } bool;
```

or even to

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define bool int
```

which makes no difference. So, it can't be related to the definition of bool (which the error indicates). In addition, the local variable `HRetVal` (which is of type bool) is not flagged as erroneous.

I also tried without declaring the parameter as `const`, which shows another error message (`"Log.h"(366,3)   Missing parameter type.`), but still does not compile.

Changing the type of parameter `Has_Return_Value` to `int` compiles happily (no surprise). On the other hand, using a plain `int` is not what is intended here.

Am I not allowed to use a parameter of a typedef enum? If so, then why (I'm using typedef'd enums in other places without any problems)? Can someone give my an explanation as to what may be wrong here?

Comment: @Rhymoid I include my own file global_definitions.h that has a definition of bool (s. above), so I think it's not necessary. But I can try to include `stdbool` instead. Just give me second to do so.

Comment: @alk Corrected that typo, thanks.

Comment: @Rhymoid ... now that I try to use `stdbool`, I remember, why I included my own definitions: there is no `stdbool` available in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're include `<stdbool.h>`, either directly or indirectly then you'll encounter problems.

Also, calling an enum `bool` is asking for trouble is you ever want your code to be used from C++. I'd recommend either a different name or a different casing (BOOL maybe) to avoid any problems. Alternatively, just stick with an `int` as it's a well understood C paradigm.